# Multi line text using Qt's QExtrudedTextMesh

Tags: pyqt5, pyside2, qt3d

Is there any way to write text in more than one line? For instance, I want to write:

*Hello*

*World!*

Each word in each line.

I know I can create two `QEntity`-s for each line but I am looking for an easier way to implement this.

```py
class MyEntity(Qt3DCore.QEntity):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        # some other code

        self.mesh = Qt3DExtras.QExtrudedTextMesh()
        self.mesh.setText("Hello World!")
        self.addComponent(self.mesh)
```

Comment: What about `\n`? This is the default Linux new line character and gives you a line break when printing text on the console etc. I.e. format your text to `"Hello\nWorld!"`.

Comment: Nope. `\n` is ignored. `"Hello\nWorld!"` is shown as *HelloWorld!*.

Comment: The reason is that the extruded geometry class uses `QPainterPath` to extract polygons from the text. This class does not support formatted text so I'm afraid there is no way to achieve this directly.